# What Blank Smart Card do I need to use to work with my E5570 Laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, authentication, smartcard

I have a smart card reader in my new laptop (Dell Latitude E5570) and I wanted to use it for windows login and other authentication processes within Windows 10.

The built-in (It seems to be a module you can buy and install directly on the motherboard, mine came with it already installed) smart card reader shows up like this in Device Manager: "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)".

The actual question is which specific Smartcard would I need to buy to be compatible with this device?

Naturally I'll just trial and error my way through the actual authentication setup once I have the smart card but first I need some that will work, but if there are any tips anyone has on setting it up once I get the cards i'll take that information as well.

Since most seem to be sold in packs (anywhere from 10 to 100) I would like to know if some of them wouldn't work with my reader.

Also, I noticed the [Dell Manual](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/latitude-e5570-laptop/LatitudeE5570_Pub/Contactless-smart-card-specifications?guid=GUID-4B89A1AB-B036-4792-8D29-C1D37617766D&lang=en-us) for this laptop claims that the reader is "Contactless". Is that true? I have a slot on the side of the laptop, maybe it can do both? This would also change which smartcards I would buy.

Comment: Are you sure the slot on the side is the smartcard reader, and not a flash card reader? (you know, sd cards, compact flash, etc) just checking.

Comment: It's definitely a Smart Card slot, It's labeled "SC" and is roughly the size of a credit card. Also I have a slot for SD cards on the other side of the laptop. Thanks for checking though, better to check before going too far down the road and realizing I didn't know what a SC reader looked like :P

Comment: Picking up the following card(PIVKey C910 PKI Smart Card) to see if it works: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SJV2CNK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1